# ICICI payment integration with php.?? where to set redirect URL.?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment-processing

i would like to integrate ICICI payment gateway for my clients website which is wrote in HTML.

i have the ICICI bank PHP payment integration kit.

i had changed everything as per the document given.. now

1. where to set the redirect URL in case of success or failure payment.??
2. how to get the calculated amount to get from my sql table to the payment page.?? i.e how to get amount to payment page..
3. how to keep file permissions for key file and other files.??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple. Just follow the Word Document in you kit.

You need 3 files only

1. Test SSL.php
2. SFAResponse.php and
3. sfa.properties

And include SFA directory too

In Test SSL u have to modify like below :

`$oMerchant->setMerchantDetails("Enter Merchant ID","Enter Merchant ID","Enter Merchant ID","10.10.10.238",rand()."","Ord1234","http://localhost/merchant/SFAResponse.php","POST","INR","INV123","req.Sale","100","","Ext1","true","Ext3","Ext4","New PHP");`

Rest values are self explanatory !

In SFAResponse.php set the following fileds

`$strMerchantId="Enter Merchant ID";`

`$astrFileName="c://key//icici//Your Merchant ID.key";`

Similarly change sfa.properties to specify the path to key file with trialing slash.

For example `c://key//icici//`

Thats it !

But read the word document clearly. All things mentioned very clearly in that document !

Comment: i had completed as per the word document. its working. but i'm unable to get the redirect url.. as after payment we should redirect the customer to sucess page of our website.. where should i set the URL.??

Comment: In SFAResponse.php page check $ResponseCode=='0' means transaction done and then you can take to ur customer to thanks page

Comment: thank you. i successfully setup that payment gateway.

Comment: Good to know that ! Enjoy !!!